# stopping a function after a set amount of time and going to the next function

Tags: c++, time, clock

I am trying to test some algorithms and while timing them, I want to stop them if they take too long (60 seconds to be exact). I have tried tinkering around with the clock function but I can't seem to get it to stop and move to the next test. I would like do this without editing the isUnique function itself. is there a way to do this by timing the operation from the start and stopping it if it elapses 60 seconds? Here is the program so far..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isUnique(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) return true;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start, end - 1))
        return false;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start + 1, end))
        return false;
    return (arr[start] != arr[end]);
}

bool isUniqueLoop(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) return true;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])return false;
    return true;
}

bool isUniqueSort(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start <= end) return true;
    vector<int> buf(arr);
    sort(buf.begin() + start, buf.begin() + end);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        if (buf[i] == buf[i + 1]) return false;
    return true;
}

int main() {

    int max = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number for the Max range: ";
    cin >> max;
    default_random_engine randGen(time(0));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> randNum(0, max);
    int i;
    int j;
    int n = randNum(randGen);
    int m = n;
    double timeout = 60.0;

    vector<int> myVect;

    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        myVect.push_back(randNum(randGen));
        //cout << myVect[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Recursive Algorithm Test... " << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // recursive algorithm
    clock_t start = clock();
    isUnique(myVect, 0, m);
    if (isUnique(myVect, 0, m) == true) { 
        cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << endl;
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
    cout << "CPU Time used for this algorithm: " << time << " ms" << endl;

    if (time > 60000) {
    cout << "This function takes too long! " << endl;
            }

    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;


    cout << "Iterative Algorithm Test... " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    // iterative algorithm
    clock_t start2 = clock();
    isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n);
    if (isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n) == true) {
        cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << endl;
    }
    clock_t end2 = clock();
    double time2 = (double)(end2 - start2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
    cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time2 << " ms. " << endl;
    if (time2 > 60000) {
        cout << "This function takes too long! " << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;


    cout << "Sort Algorithm Test... " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    // sort algorithm
    clock_t start3 = clock();
    isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n);
    if (isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n) == true) {
        cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The Vector is not Unique " << endl;
    }
    clock_t end3 = clock();
    double time3 = (double)(end3 - start3) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
    cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time3 << " ms. " << endl;
    if (time3 > 60000) {
        cout << "This function takes too long! " << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

the first isUnique() function always takes long because its ineffective and recursive, that's fine, its supposed to be that way. However, I don't know how to terminate that specific function and move to the next if it takes too long. Sorry for the wordy post. any suggestions?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How do I use that algorithm to find the largest value of n such that the algorithm runs in one minute or less?

Comment: (1) try various values of `n`. (2) "runs one minute or less" is kinda machine  (and compiler) specific...

Comment: for 60 second, invoke isUnique() counting how many times invoked?  But how big is arr?  I suggest your first experiments should be -O0.  When your code seems to work, change to -O3.  Out put is count per 60 seconds?

Comment: the question I asked is exactly how my book asks it. So again. I honestly have NO CLUE what to do, im talking from header files, how the vector needs to set up, how to time it..none of it. I don't get it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine that you run this algorithm on an input array of size n. Your algorithm fires off two recursive calls, each of which runs on an array of size n - 1, then does a constant amount of work to combine the pieces back together. This means that we can express the runtime of your algorithm as

> T(n) ≤ 2T(n - 1) + O(1)

This recurrence relation solves to O(2<sup>n</sup>), exponential in the size of the input. If you measure how long it takes on a few inputs, you should be able to extrapolate outward from there knowing that you're looking at an exponential growth curve. Specifically, every added element will double the runtime. From there, you just need to set up an equation involving 2<sup>n</sup>, one minute, and the runtime of the algorithm on some known input size and take things from there.

Comment: you're speaking greek to me. I have no Idea at all what you're talking about man. I'm new at this stuff

Comment: Your function makes two recursive calls, each of which is on an array that's effectively one step smaller than the original array. So that means you have one recursive call on an array of size n, two on an array of size n -1, four on an array of size n - 2, eight on an array of size n - 3, etc. This ends up causing there to be a *lot* of recursive calls made, in fact, an exponentially large number of them. Each time you increase the size of the problem by one, you kick off twice as many recursive calls as before, so that means it'll take roughly twice as long for the function to finish.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I still don't understand how I am supposed to figure all this out though. This is just one of three algorithms out of the book I have to test. I was hoping I could be helped out with a set of code that I would input into the isUnique() function that I can use on the other two functions I have to test.